# Catch Error response not returning as HttpErrorResponse Object

Tags: node.js, angular7, angular-httpclient

I am trying to catch the exception in the angular service method with the `catchError`.

Here, in the handleError method, I am trying to cast the error response of `HttpErrorResponse` but the response is always returning string and in this case it is returning the string `Bad Request` instead of the `HttpErrorResponse` object.

The actual error object returning from the node.js service method is of Type `Result`.

```
create(data) {

    return this.httpClient.post<Result>(this.url, JSON.stringify(data), this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(catchError(e => this.handleError(e)))
}

handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {

  let errorMessage = '';

  if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // client-side error
      errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
  } else {
      // server-side error
      //errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.failMessage}\nMessage: ${error.failMessage}`;
  }

  return throwError(error);
}
```

**Result Object**

```
export interface Result
{
    error: any;
    failMessage: string;
    okMessage: string;
}
```

And the **node.js** service

```
function create (req, res, next)
{
    service.create(req.body)
                .then(result => {
                    var statusCode = 200; //default to ok

                    if (result)
                    {
                        result.okMessage = "Category Created";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        statusCode = 400;

                        if (result.exception === "duplicate")
                        {
                            result.failMessage = `Category ${req.body.category} is already taken`;
                        }
                    }

                    res.status(statusCode).json(result)
                })
  .catch(err => next(err))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular http client module will return response body only, in case if you want all http response like headers status and body you have to use observe option, please check angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

```
this.httpOptions = { .....
        observe: 'response' 
    }
```

Example from angular docs.

```
 getConfigResponse(): Observable<HttpResponse<Config>> {
     return this.http.get<Config>(
       this.configUrl, { observe: 'response' });
   }
```

Comment: I've used this already in the `httpOptions` but still same string is returned

Comment: So, please update error response from node app to be, `res.status(statusCode).json({success: false, error 'Bad Request'});`

Comment: you are checking if not result add status code 400 , so if not result ? how come `result.exception` will have value? the code will not enter this block `if (result.exception === "duplicate")`,  so in this case define result as an object inside else block then assign any values to it .  `statusCode = 400 ; result = {} ; result.x = whatever ; result.y `

Comment: I have even hard coded and checked the response object but still it is string

Comment: Please make sure that `service.create` not thrown an exception so you response got from `next()` handler not the route handler you mentioned, so please use `console.log` everywhere inside you back end and front end code to validate if the request goes through the expected path, you can also check chrome dev tools `network tab` if the request submitted to your expected url or not, and test your back end code by postman before integrate front end with back end.

Comment: No, it is not throwing exception. When I checked in the postman it is properly getting the Bad Request status code along with result object. I am not sure what else goes wrong?!

Comment: So make sure that, front end submit request successfully to the actual url, you can check this by [chrome dev tools network tab]( https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/) , just open dev tools then submit the request , also please double check the `observe` param in request header

Comment: Will check that and let you know as that is in the different environment

Comment: It's pointing to the correct URL but still, the issue exists.